# How to install MongoDB database as a service in ESxi?

Tags: mongodb, storage, cloud

I want to know is it possible to install mongodb directly to the ESXi without guest OS?
Please tell me how to setup Data storage as a service environment inside ESXi.

Comment: There is no [MongoDB for ESXi in the supported platforms](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/installation/#supported-platforms). I don't think you can use another binary and use it "bare-metal". Mongo needs a full OS.

Comment: Can you suggest me any other option that will allow me to setup a Nosql database as a service environment inside ESXi?

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't have a VM with an OS in that metal?

Answer (score 0):

Answer is simple, you cannot do that! MongoDB cannot operate without OS, period!

Comment: What ate the options to setup a nosql database inside ESxi to provide Nosql database as a service?

Answer (score 0):

Check these resources out by VMWhere for installing SQL Server on ESxi Host Configuration: https://www.vmware.com/content/dam/digitalmarketing/vmware/en/pdf/solutions/sql-server-on-vmware-best-practices-guide.pdf

And their best practices guide: https://blogs.vmware.com/apps/2018/09/sql-server-on-vmware-august-2018.html